# Keep expression exactly as written for latex conversion

Tags: python, sympy

I want to get the expression of `p__s_alpha = 1/k * Product(a_0,(i,1,O))` in latex. I use:

```
print sympy.latex(p__s_alpha)
```

When I run latex on the result I get the following equation:

[image: incorrect]

However, I want to print this equation:

[image: correct]

Is there a way to keep the representation of the expression the way it is?

Comment: Is it feasible to manually add `\displaystyle` to the output TeX before compiling? It also seems like your use of `(i,1,O)` is going to force the start `i=1`, so can you modify that part to get no `=1` in the subscript?

Comment: Ah, the `i` in the second equation is actually a small error that I didn't notice yet, this should be i=0. I want to keep `1/k * product` instead of `product/k`, the rest of the layout is not so important.

Comment: While there are probably ways to do this by abusing the `__new__` method of the `Product` class, I think your approach as a whole is wrong. Sympy is not a typesetting library, it is a computer algebra library, so you should not expect it to focus a lot on convenience methods for typesetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started writing up an answer about how you could make your own custom printer that does this, but this I realized that there's already an option in `latex` that does what you want, the `long_frac_ratio` option. If that ratio is small enough, any fraction that is small enough will be printed as `1/b*a` instead of `a/b`.

```
In [31]: latex(p__s_alpha, long_frac_ratio=1)
Out[31]: '\\frac{1}{k} \\prod_{i=1}^{O} a_{0}'
```

---

If you're interested, here is some of what I was going to write about writing a custom printer:

Internally, SymPy makes no distinction between `a/b` and `a*1/b`. They are both represented by the exact same object (see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html).

However, the printing system is different. As you can see from that page, `a/b` is represented as `Mul(a, Pow(b, -1))`, i.e., `a*b**-1`, but it is the printer that converts this into a fraction format (this holds for any printer, not just the LaTeX one).

The good news for you is that the printing system in SymPy is very extensible (and the other good news is that SymPy is BSD open source, so you can freely reuse the printing logic that is already there in extending it).  To create a custom LaTeX printer that does what you want, you need to subclass `LatexPrinter` in `sympy.printing.latex` and override the `_print_Mul` function (because as noted above, `a/b` is a `Mul`).  The logic in this function is not really split up modularly, so you'll really need to copy the whole [source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/latex.py#L235) and change the relevant parts of it [as I noted above, for this one, there is already an option that does what you want, but in other cases, there may not be].

And a final note, if you make a modification that would probably be wanted be a wider audience, we would love to have you submit it as a pull request to SymPy.

Comment: Thanks. I won't have acces to my code until monday, I will see if the long_Frac_ratio works for me then